# how to check if a process in uninterruptable on Solaris

Tags: process, operating-system, solaris, ps

which ps option on Solaris 11g gives information if a process is in uninterruptable sleep mode?

```
admin@starsut:/tmp$ ps -aef | grep java
UID   PID  PPID   C    STIME TTY         TIME CMD
oracle  1465  1462   0   Oct 13 ?          18:10 /oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/jdk/bin/sparcv9/java -server -Xmx384M -XX:MaxPermSi
admin 15701 15680   0   Oct 19 ?        2403:01 /wls/bin/middleware/jdk160_29/bin/java -client -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermS
admin 29778  1943   0 13:05:44 ?           0:15 /wls/bin/middleware/jdk160_29/bin/java -classpath /wls/bin/middleware/patch_wls
admin 28733  1943   0 12:51:49 ?           0:15 /wls/bin/middleware/jdk160_29/bin/java -classpath /wls/bin/middleware/patch_wls
admin 29122  1943   0 12:56:03 ?           0:15 /wls/bin/middleware/jdk160_29/bin/java -classpath /wls/bin/middleware/patch_wls
admin 13115 11818   0 16:10:39 pts/8       0:00 grep java
```

I can't find any option to indicate a process (is in "D" state).

Please advise if there's such a flag.

edit: deleted linux flag

Comment: Why is this flagged `linux` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such process state 'D' in Solaris. Sources:

1. `ps(1)` man page (states: O, S, R, T, W, Z)
2. `pflags` and `pflags.c` (OpenSolaris) (`ASLEEP` seems closest to Linux's `S`, not `D`).
3. `<sys/proc.h>` and `usr/src/uts/common/sys/proc.h` (OpenSolaris again):

   ```
   #define SSLEEP  1       /* awaiting an event */
   #define SRUN    2       /* runnable */
   #define SZOMB   3       /* process terminated but not waited for */
   #define SSTOP   4       /* process stopped by debugger */
   #define SIDL    5       /* intermediate state in process creation */
   #define SONPROC 6       /* process is being run on a processor */
   #define SWAIT   7       /* process is waiting to become runnable */
   ```